# How to hide an item in datalist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datalist

I want to hide an item in `datalist` according to some condition suing `ItemBound`, how ?

Comment: Would this be a value from the datasource? If so, its probably best to remove it from the datasource in the first place. If you're using a SQL datasource, you could use a WHERE clause.

Comment: Yes, but I can't re-bind the datalist data while I am inside the ItemBound

Comment: If there is a value in the ItemBound which you need to check, surely you have this available from the datasource?

Comment: no the value is computed dynamically

Comment: If switching from `asp:DataList` to `asp:ListView` would be an option for you my updated answer would work.

Comment: I realize this is to late but `e.Item.Controls.Clear()` would work.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap a `PlaceHolder` control around the entire content of the `ItemTemplate`.

Then in your ItemDataBound event, you could do something like:

```
Protected Sub myDataList_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles myDataList.ItemDataBound
    If Not Value = Value2 Then
       Ctype(e.Item.FindControl("myPlaceHolder"), PlaceHolder).Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

---

A better approach (however I've not had chance to test it), would be to hide the whole item using `e.Item.Visible`. This way no HTML table elements would be rendered for the item. It would also mean no `PlaceHolder` would have to be added.

```
Protected Sub myDataList_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles myDataList.ItemDataBound
    If Not Value = Value2 Then
       e.Item.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Alternatively, if the values you are checking are from a database source, you could filter the items out before binding:

```
WHERE Value=@Value2
```

Comment: Did you try if `DataList` will create empty rows for those hidden items? I figure it will look the same as my approach.

Comment: @Filburt I've improved the answer to include a possible option of hiding the item.

Comment: I tried your improved example but ItemDataBound doesn't seem to work; even if I set `e.Item.Visible` always to `False` it still creates all items.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to set the visibility of your Item container by evaluating your desired condition in your ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div id="itemdiv" visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("YourValue")) == 5) %>' runat="server">
        <%# Eval("SomeOtherValue") %>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

My example uses a constant but you could use any variable in scope.

**Pitfall!**

`DataList` will insist to create empty rows for hidden items, so you may have to use `ListView` instead to fully control creating your filtered itemlist.

---

**Update**

Using a `ListView` instead will only create rows for visible items:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr id="itemdiv" visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("YourValue")) == 5) %>' runat="server">
        <td><%# Eval("SomeOtherValue") %></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table border="1">
        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
```