# Hide deleted row, from DataList without rebinding the DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please consider these operations -

1. Bind a list of files in a **DataList**.
2. Once the user clicks delete **LinkButton**, delete the file, in
   **ItemCommandEvent**.
3. Since rebinding whole data is inefficient, I am simply hiding
   deleted row.

Following code displays files in a DataList. There is a delete button beside each row.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand" runat="server">                
    <ItemTemplate>        
        <tr>
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("ContainingFolder") as string + "\\" + Eval("FileName") as string %>' 
                Visible="false" ID="lblFullPath" runat="server" />
            <td><%# Eval("FileName") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("ContainingFolder") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("FileSize") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Modified") %></td>
            <td>
                <asp:LinkButton Text="Delete" ID="linkDelete" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>            
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

In ItemCommand Event Handler this code deletes the selected file from this list.

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem) return;

    var selectedItem = e.Item.FindControl("lblFullPath") as Label;

    e.Item.Visible = false;       //doesn't work     

    File.Delete(selectedItem.Text);
}
```

However **e.Item.Visible = false** does not hides the row.
As a workaround found here, [How to hide an item in datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394887/how-to-hide-an-item-in-datalist)

I have wrapped contents inside a placeholder control.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph1" runat="server">
        <%--wrapped content--%>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</ItemTemplate>
```

And hiding the placeholder control -

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem) return;

    var selectedItem = e.Item.FindControl("lblFullPath") as Label;
    //e.Item.Visible = false;
    e.Item.FindControl("ph1").Visible = false;
    File.Delete(selectedItem.Text);
}
```

> Generally in asp.net hiding parent control hides all of its child controls.

But I am not able to understand,

> Why hiding the parent control e.Item doesn't hide its containing
>   elements, in case of DataList ? Can you please advise.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:** Updating more info about generating list of files to display in DataList.

- Generating fileList at runtime on button click, **this list is not
  persistent, currently.**

> ```
> protected void btnFindDuplicates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     DataList1.DataSource = FindDuplicates();
>     DataList1.DataBind();
> }
> ```

- In the event handler of delete Click, delete operation has been
  completed successfully.
- So, just to remove deleted item from the page, It would not be wise
  to regenerate the dataSource and bind this. Hiding seems more logical to me.

Comment: `DataList` is a databound control - why do you feel that rebinding the whole list is inefficient?

Comment: Hi Tim, I judged this based on two facts. 1. Considering a file listing of 100+ rows in the DataList, since it is known that only one row is going to be deleted. IMO rebinding whole list could be costly.

Comment: Dude, you could use cache... besides, it's even worst to use the ViewState to keep track of the list content. If your concern is about performance, place the list data in the cache and disabled the VieState of the list, rebinding it every time from the cache. Additionally add a SQL cache dependency to your cached object

Comment: @Tim Second, since the end result is, deleting selected file on the disk. Not currently caching the modified data in list. What do you say?

Comment: @autrevo are you intersted in a highly efficient solution involving jQuery and a Web Service (ASMX, WCF, Page Method, Web API, REST WCF)?

Comment: @autrevo - I don't think the performance cost for rebinding would be that much.  When is the selected file deleted?  Why not just delete the file and then rebind?   What is the flow of events you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Tim Have added more info, pls review. The issue here, is for simple application I am not storing list of files in persistent storage.

Comment: @Jupaol Yes, That would be good, please advise.

Comment: @autrevo You definitely need to check to cost of rebinding the list before you decide on another solution. It all depends on how poorly/good the `FindDuplicates` method is written.

Comment: @autorevo I agree with Magnus.  Can you post your FindDuplicates code (as well as the code you use to generate the list initially)?  I think any performance gains to be had will be in there, not in rebinding the list.

Comment: @Tim Hi Tim, I have posted the code here and using the updated version as replied by Jon Skeet -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763797/list-duplicate-files-inside-a-folder-in-c-leveraging-linq-asparallel/12764380#12764380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this sample using JQuery and PageMethods:

#### Result

[image]

#### ASPX

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var $list = $("table[id*=myDataListID]");
        var $buttons = $("input:submit[id*=remove]", $list);

        $buttons.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                return false;
            }

            var $self = $(this);
            var $jobID = $self.closest("tr").children().find("span[id*=jobID]");

            $buttons.prop("disabled", true);

            $.ajax({
                url: "<%: this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Topics/JQuery/Ajax/RemoveRowUsingJQueryAfterCallingService.aspx/Remove") %>",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{id: " + $jobID.text() + "}",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function () {
                    $buttons.prop("disabled", false);
                    $self.closest("tr").remove();
                },
                error: function (XHResponse, errorMessage, errorCode) {
                    $buttons.prop("disabled", false);
                    alert(errorMessage);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:DataList runat="server" DataKeyField="job_id" DataSourceID="lds" ID="myDataListID">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <tr>
            <th>
                &nbsp;
            </th>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button Text="Remove" runat="server" ID="remove" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("job_id") %>' runat="server" ID="jobID" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="jobDesc" Text='<%# Eval("job_desc") %>' runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

#### Code behind

```
[WebMethod]
public static void Remove(Int16 id)
{
    // simulate deleting the file
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

[I just uploaded the full working example to my GitHub site](https://github.com/jupaol/SO-Answers/blob/master/Visual%20Studio%202012/src/SO/WebForms/WebForms_1/Topics/JQuery/Ajax/RemoveRowUsingJQueryAfterCallingService.aspx)

Comment: Interesting approach - it seems a bit of overkill to use a web service here, especially if it's all on the same machine.  Am I missing something?

Comment: That's why I used a PageMethod. Services are used to work with AJAX calls to create RIA's. It doesn't matter if they are from the same application dude. What I believe is that you have a design problem instead of a technical one. And your comment only indicates that you do not work with JQuery-AJAX often, probably that's what you are missing. When you try AJAX the responsiveness of your application will be increased significatively

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, though I think you got me confused with the OP :)  90% of what I do is in the middle tier/data layer, so I don't use AJAX or jQuery very often (and have not used RIA at all).

Comment: A bit late to do +1, Thanks Jupaol.